# Using different Dexie Cloud configs for different environments with Nuxt3

Tags: pm2, nuxt3, dexie

I'm writing an app using Nuxt3 and Dexie Cloud, deploying with PM2 to my dev Ubuntu webserver on my LAN. All was well, until I decided to to add another deployment, which I would treat as "production", to mimic the end user's setup. I won't be able to just delete databases and tables there, so I am preparing to run it on a separate database.

I planned changing the db name in the instantiation to a variable (`new Dexie(bdVar)`) and the same for the url in `db.cloud.configure`.

And that's where things blew up... Cause... Where do I get the values for those variables from? `.env` doesn't work as I thought it would (Node, runtime, etc). Nuxt's `runtimceConfig`... well, still trying to wrap my head around that.

Let me give an overview of what I have:

```js
// db/index.js
import { Dexie } from 'dexie'
import { dexieCloud } from 'dexie-cloud-addon'

export const db = new Dexie(dexieDb***, {addons: [dexieCloud]})

db.version(1).stores({
  // table definitions
})

db.cloud.configure({
  databaseUrl: dexieDbUrl***,
  requireAuth: true
})
*** means it works fine when string provided
```

Then I have a few other db files, each with related queries/transactions

```js
// db/items.dexie.js
import { db } from '~/db/index.js'

export const fetchItems = async (realmId) => {
  const result = await db.items.where('realmId').equals(realmId).sortBy('last_update')
  return result
}
...
```

Then I have my Pinia stores, items store, shortened, as example

```js
// stores/items.js 
import { fetchItems } from '~/db/items.dexie.js'

export const useItemStore = defineStore('items', () => {
  let items = ref([])

  const getItems = async () => {
    if (items.value.length === 0) items.value = await fetchItems(currentSpace.value.realmId)
    return items
  }

  ...

  return {
    items,
    getItems,
    ...
  }
})
```

A simple example of a page:

```js
// pages/items.vue
<script setup>
const { items } = storeToRefs(useItemStore())

onMounted(async () => {
  if (items.value.length < 1) items.value = await useItemStore().getItems()
})
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried adding the runtimeConfig in the nuxt.conf.ts:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    dexieDb: '', // .env entry: NUXT_DEXIE_DB
    dexieDbUrl: '', // .env entry: NUXT_DEXIE_DB_URL
  },
})
```

The next logical step (in my head, of course) would be to now access the runtimeConfig in db/index.js:

```js
// db/index.js
import ...

const runtime = useRuntimeConfig()

export const db = new Dexie(runtime.dexieDb, {addons: [dexieCloud]})
...
```

The 500 error does clearly explain that this won't work:
`A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function.`

And this is where I'm stuck at the moment. How do I make the Dexie db available, while using variables that will have different values, depending on the environment, while using "a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function"?

Note: Some of the information I need to have as variables is sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to bed with this question in my head. Woke up with a "solution". Although there might be a more elegant way of doing this, this is what I came up with:

First, I moved `db/index.js` into a plugin

```js
// plugins/dexie.js
import { Dexie } from 'dexie'
import { dexieCloud } from 'dexie-cloud-addon'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
  
  const db = new Dexie(runtimeConfig.public.dexieDb, {addons: [dexieCloud]})

  db.version(1).stores({
    // table definitions
  })

  db.cloud.configure({
    databaseUrl: runtimeConfig.public.dexieDbUrl,
    requireAuth: true
  })

  nuxtApp.db = db
})
```

Moved the variables to the `public runtimeConfig`

```js
// nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      dexieDb: '', // env var NUXT_PUBLIC_DEXIE_DB
      dexieDbUrl: '', // env var NUXT_PUBLIC_DEXIE_DB_URL
    },
  },
  ...
})
```

Then I changed the db methods to expect a reference to the db

```js
// db/items.dexie.js
export const fetchItems = async (db, realmId) => {
  return await db.items.where('realmId').equals(realmId).sortBy('last_update')
}
...
```

In the stores I get the db from the NuxtApp, and pass it along

```js
// stores/items.js 
import { fetchItems } from '~/db/items.dexie.js'

export const useItemStore = defineStore('items', () => {
  const { db } = useNuxtApp()

  let items = ref([])

  const getItems = async () => {
    if (items.value.length === 0) items.value = await fetchItems(db, currentSpace.value.realmId)
    return items
  }

  ...

  return {
    items,
    getItems,
    ...
  }
})
```

This worked great in dev! It uses the `.env` in the project root.

For "production" I needed to update the `ecosystem.config.cjs`, adding the env variables (I'm using [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/))

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
      name: 'InstanceName',
      port: '3005',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      instances: '2',
      script: './.output/server/index.mjs',
      env: {
        'NUXT_PUBLIC_DEXIE_DB': 'home-db',
        'NUXT_PUBLIC_DEXIE_DB_URL': 'https://xxxxxxxxx.dexie.cloud'
      },
    }]
}
```

Now I have my local dev, and two instances on my LAN webserver: One "dev" (using the same db as my local, so I can delete and update. and mess around as much as I want) and one "production" (using a separate db, as it would be in the actual production.

I hope this helps someone who gets stuck with this...